# How to test an Airflow connection after creating it?

Tags: airflow

I have created a connection using Airflow Admin. The connection is to Azure Data Lake. How will I test the connection?

Thanks

Pkumar

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to test it from the UI itself. The easiest way to test is simply schedule some DAG. You can use the  following DAG which will list all the Parquet files from `folder/output/`
folder in the specified ADLS account :

```
from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.microsoft.azure.operators.adls_list import AzureDataLakeStorageListOperator
from datetime import datetime

with models.DAG(
    "example_adls_list",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 06, 20),
    schedule_interval="@once",
    tags=['testing_connection'],
) as dag:
        adls_files = AzureDataLakeStorageListOperator(
            task_id='adls_files',
            path='folder/output/*.parquet',
            azure_data_lake_conn_id='azure_data_lake_default'
        )
```

Comment: I tried this and I am getting this error [2021-06-29 14:02:32,348] {taskinstance.py:1153} ERROR - HTTP error: ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='testgroupfiles.azuredatalakestore.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/testcontainers?OP=LISTSTATUS&api-version=2018-09-01&listSize=4000 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0473fdf630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))",),)